# How to set up Azure deployment pipeline to App Service with Nx and Express

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, nomachine-nx

I am struggling to have the deployment of an Express app succeed.

I have an Nx Monorepo set up with Azure Repos. In this monorepo, I have 4 projects and I am trying to deploy one that uses Express. I can't seem to find anywhere how to do this and since this is my first deployment from a monorepo, I'm not sure how all the documentation from various sources fits together.

I have included my YAML file below. It succeeds in the Build Stage, but fails during Deploy.
Whenever I run the `nx build` command, it puts the output into the /dist/apps folder in the root directory.

Some of the kudu logs show a 409 conflict error but I'm not sure what could be causing this.

```
# Node.js Express Web App to Linux on Azure
# Build a Node.js Express app and deploy it to Azure as a Linux web app.
# Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/javascript

trigger:
- main

variables:

  # Azure Resource Manager connection created during pipeline creation
  azureSubscription: <hidden>

  # Web app name
  webAppName: 'mean-api'

  # Environment name
  environmentName: 'mean-api'

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    - task: NodeTool@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '16.x'
      displayName: 'Install Node.js'
    
    - script: 
        npm install --force
      displayName: 'npm install'
    
    - script: 
        npx nx build mean-api --if-present
      displayName: 'npm build'
    
    - script: 
        npx nx test mean-api --if-present
      displayName: 'npm test'

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: $(environmentName)
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: AzureWebApp@1
            displayName: 'Azure Web App Deploy: mean-api'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
              appType: webAppLinux
              appName: $(webAppName)
              runtimeStack: 'NODE|16-lts'
              package: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip
```